# formating of dates in sql server

Tags: sql-server

This is my query

```
select projectname,CONCAT([Budget Health],[ProjectBaseline0StartDate],[ProjectActualStartDate],[ProjectStartDate]) as budgethealth from [dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView]
```

Output is:

```
projectname | budgethealth 
abc         |< 5% varianceApr  7 2015  8:00AMApr  7 2015  8:00AMApr  7  2015  8:00AM
```

I want info of budget health in this form:

```
<5% variance
Apr/07/2015
Apr/08/2015
Apr/08/2015
```

I want time to be removed and date in this format.

Comment: Please don't post your question [to multiple sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988515/formating-of-dates-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

You can format DateTime as follow:

> CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)

Ex:

```
CONVERT(varchar(11),[ProjectBaseline0StartDate])
```

Full Query:

```
select projectname,CONCAT([Budget Health],Convert(varchar(11),[ProjectBaseline0StartDate]),CONVERT(varchar(11),[ProjectActualStartDate]),CONVERT(varchar(11),[ProjectStartDate])) as budgethealth from [dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView]
```

Please look for detailed information and style options: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: yeah bro time is removed.but how do i get these dtaes in new line.@http://superuser.com/users/113459/murat